Как передаются массивы разных размеров в функцию?
Вопрос довольно тривиальный, и есть множество ответов на данный вопрос. И поверьте я прочитал очень много по этому вопросу. Я могу скопировать решение для моего конкретного случая, но моя голова взрывается, потому что я не могу систематизировать знания и из-за этого не могу двигаться вперёд.
Меня не совсем интересует поиск "совета как сделать", мне нужно чтобы подтвердили/опровергли/дополнили мою картину мира по вопросу "передача массива в функцию".
И так что я знаю на данный момент:
//        ОДНОМЕРНЫЙ МАССИВ
по значению с определенным размером
Функция: void func(int massive[10]){}
Вызов в программе: func(massive);
по значению с неопределенным размером
Функция: void func(int massive[], int massiveSize){}
Вызов в программе: func(myMassive, 10);
по ссылке c определенным размером
Функция: void func(int (&massive)[10]){}
Вызов в программе: func(myMassive);
по ссылке c определенным размером
Функция: void func(int (&massive)[], int massiveSize){}
Вызов в программе: func(myMassive, 10);
по указателю с неопределенным размером (при этом если внутри функции будем мерить sizeof() указателя, то получим размер 4 байта - одного int
Функция: void func(int *massive, massiveSize){};
Вызов в программе: func(&myMassive,10);
//        ДВУМЕРНЫЙ МАССИВ
по значению с определенным размером
Функция: void func(int massive[5][10]){}
Вызов в программе: func(myMassive);
по значению с неопределенным размером - но мы должны указать размерность второго измерения, то есть кол-во столбцов
Функция: void func( int massive[][10],int sizeRows){}
Вызов в программе: func(myMassive, 5);
по ссылке с неопределенным размером
Функция: void func(int& (*massive)[],int sizeRows, sizeCollums){}
Вызов в программе:
rows = sizeof(massive)/sizeof(*massive);
collums = sizeof(massive[0])/sizeof(massive[0][0]);
func (massive, rows,collums);

по ссылке с определенным размером
Функция: void func(int& (*massive[5])[10]){}
Вызов в программе: func(myMassive);
по указателю на первый элемент
Функция: void func(int* (&massive), sizeRows, sizeCollums){};
Вызов в программе:
rows = sizeof(massive)/sizeof(*massive);
collums = sizeof(massive[0])/sizeof(massive[0][0]);
func( (int*)massive, rows,collums);

//        ТРЁХМЕРНЫЙ МАССИВ
по указателю на первый элемент, больше рабочего кода для себя я не нашёл
Функция: void func(int* (&massive), sizeDimension1, sizeDimension2,sizeDimension3){};
Вызов в программе:
dimension1 = sizeof(massive)/sizeof(*massive);
dimension2 = sizeof(massive[0])/sizeof(massive[0][0]);
dimension3 = sizeof(massive[0][0])/sizeof(massive[0][0][0]);
func( (int*)massive, dimension1,dimension2,dimension3);

Бонусный вопрос, как панчлайн к шутке:
А есть ли смысл, что я вообще так сильно запариваюсь с массивами?
Потому что я пока не приступил к изучению и освоению всех контейнеров из STL, насколько я понимаю, то в данном случае просто проще начать пользоваться контейнером array.


непонятен вопрос, если в том, правильная ли картина мира, то нет, никаких определенных размеров нет, массив при передаче в функцию становится указателем, т.е. определить его размер уже нельзя. 2) используйте vector - он в 2 раза медленнее, зато имеет метод получения кол-ва элементов и позволяет хранить большее кол-во элементов, чем массив (не хранится непрерывным куском в памяти).


@АлексейОбухов, не вводите людей в заблуждение - Вы трижды написали глупость про std::vector. 1) Он гарантированно хранит все элементы одним куском - это написано в документации:The elements are stored contiguously. 2) Нет, он ровно в 2 раза не медленнее статического массива (откуда Вы это взяли? Он что, хранит данные в физически другой памяти? - доступ к элементам массива одинаков, отличается время выделения памяти (но тоже не в 2 раза)). 3) Он может хранить больше элементов по сравнению с массивами на стеке, но еще же есть глобальные.

медленнее и значительно, но это неважно для такого быстрого языка, как c++. согласен про непрерывность, тут мой косяк. действительно, использование им кучи дает ему преимущество перед массивом. также как динамическое изменение размера (что простой массив не может). спасибо за уточнения, 100 лет уже не писал на этом языке. добра вам )

Одномерные массивы

Получение размера массива: для этого есть специальная функция в стандартной библиотеке. Типичная ошибка использовать для этих целей sizeof.

#include <iterator>
#include <cstddef>
using item_t = int;
using items_t = item_t [10];
int main()
{
    items_t items{};
    ::std::size_t items_count{::std::size(items)}; // 10
}


Передача указателя на первый элемент массива и размера массива: работает с массивами конкретного размера и неопределенного размера. Указатель потенциально может быть нулевым. Ответственность за указание правильного размера лежит на вызывающей стороне. Создание временного объекта с типом указателя на первый элемент массива из объекта с типом массива языком допускается даже неявное.

#include <iterator>
#include <cstddef>
using item_t = int;
using items_t = item_t [10];
void func(item_t * p_items, ::std::size_t items_count)
{}
int main()
{
    items_t items{};
    // то же самое func(static_cast<item_t *>(items), ::std::size(items));
    // то же самое func(::std::addressof(items[0]), ::std::size(items));
    func(items, ::std::size(items));
}


Передача массива конкретного размера по значению: языком не поддерживается. При указании массива в качестве типа аргумента тип будет заменен компилятором на указатель на элемент массива. По сути получается как при передаче указателя на первый элемент, но без указания размера.

#include <type_traits>
using item_t = int;
using items_t = item_t [10];
void func(items_t items)
{
    static_assert(::std::is_same_v<item_t *, decltype(items)>);
}

Так как передается указатель, то узнать размер массива внутри функции нельзя, а при передаче можно передвать нулевой указатель и размер не проверяется:
#include <iterator>
#include <cstddef>
using item_t = int;
using items_t = item_t [10];
void func(items_t items)
{
    ::std::size_t items_count{::std::size(items)}; // error
}
int main()
{
    func(nullptr); // компилятору все равно
    item_t small[5]{};
    func(small); // компилятору все равно
}


Передача массива неопределенного размера по значению: языком не поддерживается. При указании массива в качестве типа аргумента тип будет заменен компилятором на указатель на элемент массива. По сути получается как при передаче указателя на первый элемент, но без указания размера.

#include <type_traits>
using item_t = int;
using items_t = item_t [];
void func(items_t items)
{
    static_assert(::std::is_same_v<item_t *, decltype(items)>);
}

Узнать размер массива внутри функции нельзя, а при передаче можно передавать нулевой указатель:
#include <iterator>
#include <cstddef>
using item_t = int;
using items_t = item_t [];
void func(items_t items)
{
    ::std::size_t items_count{::std::size(items)}; // error
}
int main()
{
    func(nullptr); // компилятору все равно
}


Передача массива конкретного размера по ссылке: работает без проблем. Внутри функции можно получить размер массива, а при вызове компилятор отловит попытки передать массив другого размера или нулевой указатель.

#include <iterator>
#include <cstddef>
using item_t = int;
using items_t = item_t [10];
void func(items_t & items)
{
    ::std::size_t items_count{::std::size(items)}; // 10
}
int main()
{
    items_t items{};
    func(items); // OK
    func(nullptr); // error
    item_t small[5]{};
    func(small); // error
}


Передача массива неопределенного размера по ссылке: возможно, но бесполезно. Внутри функции получить размер массива нельзя, а при вызове компилятор отловит попытки передать нулевой указатель.

#include <iterator>
#include <cstddef>
using item_t = int;
using items_t = item_t [];
void func(items_t & items)
{
    ::std::size_t items_count{::std::size(items)}; // error
}
int main()
{
    item_t items[10];
    func(items); // OK
    func(nullptr); // error
    item_t small[5]{};
    func(small); // OK
}


Передача массива конкретного размера по указателю: работает без проблем. Внутри функции можно получить размер массива, а при вызове компилятор отловит попытки передать массив другого размера.

#include <iterator>
#include <memory>
#include <cstddef>
using item_t = int;
using items_t = item_t [10];
void func(items_t * p_items)
{
    ::std::size_t items_count{::std::size(*p_items)}; // 10
}
int main()
{
    items_t items{};
    func(::std::addressof(items)); // OK
    func(nullptr); // OK
    item_t small[5]{};
    func(::std::addressof(small)); // error
}


Передача массива неопределенного размера по указателю: возможно, но еще более бесполезно, чем по ссылке. Внутри функции получить размер массива нельзя. При вызове ничего не проверяется.

#include <iterator>
#include <memory>
#include <cstddef>
using item_t = int;
using items_t = item_t [];
void func(items_t * p_items)
{
    ::std::size_t items_count{::std::size(*p_items)}; // error
}
int main()
{
    item_t items[10];
    func(::std::addressof(items)); // OK
    func(nullptr); // OK
    item_t small[5]{};
    func(::std::addressof(small)); // OK
}

Двумерные массивы

Являются одномерными массивами, элементами которых являются другие массивы. Так что к ним приминимо все из предыдущего раздела.

using item_t = int [10];
using items_t = item_t [10];

А еще в языке есть

Обертка для массивов ::std::array, позволяющая передавать массивы по значению, которые следует всегда использовать вместо c-style массивов.
Проекции массивов ::std::span или array_view, хранящие указатель на первый элемент и размер.

